# How to send value of radio button to other page

Tags: php, html

I have a table with radio buttons to get the row values and 2 buttons

1 button.)For printing data , which moves to "notice.php"

2 button.)For row details,which stays on the same page.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
    <th>sourceID</th>
    ....
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $tot; ?>" /></td>
            <td>1</td>
            ....
            <td>open</td>
    </tr>
<input type="button" name="issue" value="Issue Notice"  onClick="location.href='notice.php'"  />
    <input type="submit" name="details" value="details"  />
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['details']))
    {
    $n=$_POST['ID'];
$a=implode("</br>",$n);
echo$a;
    }
```

Notice.php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$n=$_POST['ID'];

}?>
```

The problem here is: My code is working perfectly fine with the button details.
But it doesnt work with issue, i.e after selecting radio button and clicking on the issue notice button :it gives  Undefined index: ID in D:\XAMPP\notice.php.
kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Your details button is a submit button, so it submits the form.  However your other button is just a regular button and you use javascript to send the browser to notice.php.  As such, it does not post any data to notice.php.

You could include the data on the query string and send it that way, e.g.:

```
location.href="notice.php?id=<?=$tot?>"
```

Or you could also have the issue button post the page, and then have your receiving page check which submit button was used.  If the issue button was used you could then have the php code post to notice.php.

Comment: location.href="notice.php?id=<?=$tot?>" is not working :( In my actual code I have used $tot inside a for loop in my table. Plz plz help me plz

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code is the exact same as having a link:

`<input type="button" name="issue" value="Issue Notice" onClick="location.href='notice.php'"  />`

As in, this will not change the form `action` and submit the POST data to your new page.

You would need something like:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="unique-form-name">
    <input type="radio" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $tot; ?>">
    <input type="button" id="unique-btn-name" value="Issue Notice">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('unique-btn-name').onclick = function(){
    document['unique-form-name'].action='notice.php';
    document['unique-form-name'].submit();
}
</script>
```

Then, once you get the data to `notice.php`, you'll have to use the data as an array (you won't be able to echo the data):

```
$IDs = $_POST['ID'];
echo '<pre>',print_r($IDs),'</pre>';
```

Comment: I used ur code but  Its not getting loaded to notice.php . :(

Comment: My code is only an example. You will have to adapt your own code to get it to work. It's not simply copy paste.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="radio" name="ID" value="<?php echo $tot; ?>" />
```

Your error is the name attribute.

Also the other button is not related to the form at all. You may want to use ajax here.

Comment: name has to be ID[ ] beacause its an array.My question is ID is not transfered to notice.php.

Comment: radiobuttons are not multiple choice. so only one value can be returned.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio